# Delete the SQL query after use

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm looking for a way to delete the SQL-Query after I have used it to fill a table.
The problem is that the values in the query are kept until I change it in the textboxes.
This is my code:

```vb
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim UserEntry As Boolean = False
        Dim SQL As String = "" 'Das SQL Query wird als String definiert. Das Query dient der Abfrage von SQL Daten
        If Not tab1 Is Nothing Then 'Wenn tab1 einen Inhalt hat geschieht das Nachfolgende
            If tab1.Rows.Count > 0 Then 'Wenn tab1 mehr Rows als 0 hat wird
                SQL = Cobra.Components.Common.DBModul.ConnectionTools.ElliminateNullVallues(tab1.Rows(2).Item("SQLQuery"), True)
                'Das SQL Query aus der Datenbank genauer der Tabelle "zzMSearchQuerys" aus der Spalte "SQL Query" ausgelesen
            End If
        End If
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SQL) Then 'Sollte das Query nicht existieren, so wird ein eigenes Query definiert
            SQL = "Select * from PAT" 'Dies ist das Ersatz Query sollte das erste nicht wie gewünscht funktionieren oder
            'Nicht vorhanden sein.
        End If
        Dim Oper As String = " Where " 'Der Hilfsoperator wird definiert als "Where"
        For Each var As Object In Grid2.Children 'Die Children in Grid2 werden als Objekt in der Variable var gespeichert
            If TypeOf (var) Is myTextbox Then 'Wenn der Typ von var eine Textbox ist geschieht folgendes:
                Dim txtb1 As myTextbox = CType(var, myTextbox) 'txtb1 wird als MyTextbox definiert mit dem Inhalt von var
                Dim txtf As String = txtb1.RetWhere 'txtf wird als Textbox definiert mit dem Inhalt der Funktion RetWhere
                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtf) Then
                    SQL += Oper + txtf 'Wenn in den Textboxen etwas steht wird das zusammengesetzt mit dem Query dem Oper und dem eingegebenen Text
                    Oper = " AND " 'Der Oper wird zu AND, dies geschieht nun für jede Textbox im Formular
                    UserEntry = True 'Sollte etwas in den Textboxen steht wird UserEntry zu True
                End If
                txtf = Nothing
            End If
        Next
        If UserEntry = True Then 'Wenn UserEntry = True ist, werden die Inhalte in "tab"also der Datentabelle eingesetzt
            Dim tab As New DataTable
            DataBaseConnection.FillTable(SQL, tab, True)
            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = tab.DefaultView
            MsgBox(SQL)
        End If
```

I'm looking for a way to completely clear the Query    before the Sub has ended.
Every help appreciated. 
(Sorry for my Bad english..)
Kind Regards

Comment: WHat do You mean by "the Query will be completely cleared" ?

Comment: Before i found the Solution the Query stayed

Select * from Database where Name Like '%Pet%' even if i cleared the values in the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think more details would be nice.

At this point my solution would be this simple:

Dim tab As New DataTable
            DataBaseConnection.FillTable(SQL, tab, True)
            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = tab.DefaultView
            MsgBox(SQL)
            **SQL = ""**

Comment: Thank you. But i found the Problem. I forgott to clear a value which is a part of the SQL.

Comment: Sounds great :)